# C# System.Windows.Forms.... missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Today my solution broke on 'Rebuild'. This solution as been working for 3 years now. Literally just moved a textbox and label up and on rebuild i got 148+- errors.
All my assembly references are added and in correct version. I should add that before i moved the textbox and label the project ran with no issues.

Im going to try explain the situation using some screenshots. This example will be on a button but it breaks on anything that changes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

These two code blocks is to show how it changed after the move of the button.

Can anyone maybe direct me in a direction where i can actually fix this and get the solution to work? Or just tell me why this is happening.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Close the solution then delete /bin, /obj folders and *.suo files (and also the .vs folder if it exists), then reload and rebuild.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewWatson. I tried your suggestion, but no successes.